# ContextMenu not working on JavaFX2 TextArea?

Tags: javafx-2

This is not working for me, the context menu doesn't get displayed:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

/**
 *
 * @author Alvaro
 */
public class TextAreaContextMenu extends Application {
    Group root = new Group();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        TextArea t = new TextArea();
        ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
        m.setOnShowing(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Showing...");
            }
        });
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Item");
        m.getItems().add(item);
        t.setContextMenu(m);
        root.getChildren().add(t);  
        primaryStage.show();
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Is this a bug? or am I doing something wrong?
I'm running jdk1.7.0_02, and I think JavaFX 2.0.2 SDK.
BTW, how do I find out, exactly which JavaFX SDK version I have installed?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me with JavaFX 2.1 dev build on Windows. Right-click on text area shows menu with one element named "item".

Can you try 2.1 dev version?

You can find out your current version by running next code:

```
        System.out.println(com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo.getVersion());
```

Comment: Hey Sergey, thanks for your help as usual. I was running 2.0.3. I tried it on 2.1 beta and it's working fine. Thanks.